# Joining a calculated field to a field in another table

Tags: sql-server

I have created a variable table called Table_A which has two columns, Age and Age_Range. The Datatype for Age is integer.

The next stage is a select statement where I’m pulling the Order_Number and a calculated field from Table_B. I want to join the calculated field from Table_B with Age from Table_A, so that I can see what the range is against the calculated field and its order number.

My first attempt was:

```
SELECT Order_Number, DATEDIFF(DAY,Order_Date,CAST(GETDATE()AS DATE)) AS Ageing, Age_Range
FROM Table_B LEFT JOIN Table_A ON Table_B.Ageing = Table_A.Age_Range
```

This didn’t work and I understand why. Usually in Access, I would just build the first query with the calculated field and then build the second query joining the calculated field with the desired field from the table. I’ve been looking at sub queries and derived tables, which I believe may solve my problem, but I’m not having any luck. I know this is a basic question, but I’ve just started out with SQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot join like that because SELECT is executed after JOIN statement.
You can read about it here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/70efeffe-76b9-4b7e-b4a1-ba53f5d21916/order-of-execution-of-sql-queries

You can make a workaround using CROSS APPLY

```
SELECT Order_Number
    , T.Ageing
    , A.Age_Range
FROM Table_B AS B
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, B.Order_Date, GETDATE())) AS T(Ageing)
LEFT JOIN Table_A AS A
    ON T.Ageing = Table_A.Age_Range
```

Answer (score 0):

If the beauty of the code is not neccesarry:

```
SELECT Order_Number, DATEDIFF(DAY,Order_Date,CAST(GETDATE()AS DATE)) AS Ageing, Age_Range
FROM Table_B LEFT JOIN Table_A ON DATEDIFF(DAY,Order_Date,CAST(GETDATE()AS DATE)) = Table_A.Age_Range
```

Otherwise use CROSS APPLY as already suggested (performance will be the same). By the way, you do not need to CAST getdate() to date, DATEDIFF will work without that, so you can easily write like that:

```
SELECT Order_Number, DATEDIFF(DAY,Order_Date,GETDATE()) AS Ageing, Age_Range
FROM Table_B LEFT JOIN Table_A ON DATEDIFF(DAY,Order_Date,GETDATE()) = Table_A.Age_Range
```